# Magento 2 - Overwrite the processPaymentConfiguration method in the Module_Checkout/LayoutProcessor to overwrite the billing-address js component

Tags: magento2, checkout, billing-address

My goal is to overwrite the `billing-address.js` component so that I can add some custom bindings to a certain element on the `billing-information.html` template.

I figured out that the `module-checkout/block/checkout/LayoutProcessor.php` `processPaymentConfiguration` method is responsible in initializing the `billing-address` js component.

**module-checkout/block/checkout/LayoutProcessor.php**

```
 /**
     * Inject billing address component into every payment component
     *
     * @param array $configuration list of payment components
     * @param array $elements attributes that must be displayed in address form
     * @return array
     */
    private function processPaymentConfiguration(array &$configuration, array $elements)
    {
        $output = [];
        foreach ($configuration as $paymentGroup => $groupConfig) {
            foreach ($groupConfig['methods'] as $paymentCode => $paymentComponent) {
                if (empty($paymentComponent['isBillingAddressRequired'])) {
                    continue;
                }
                $output[$paymentCode . '-form'] = [
                    'component' => 'Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address',
                    'displayArea' => 'billing-address-form-' . $paymentCode,
                    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'deps' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'dataScopePrefix' => 'billingAddress' . $paymentCode,
                    'sortOrder' => 1,
                    'children' => [
                        'form-fields' => [
                            'component' => 'uiComponent',
                            'displayArea' => 'additional-fieldsets',
                            'children' => $this->merger->merge(
                                $elements,
                                'checkoutProvider',
                                'billingAddress' . $paymentCode,
                                [
                                    'country_id' => [
                                        'sortOrder' => 115,
                                    ],
                                    'region' => [
                                        'visible' => false,
                                    ],
                                    'region_id' => [
                                        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/region',
                                        'config' => [
                                            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                                            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/select',
                                            'customEntry' => 'billingAddress' . $paymentCode . '.region',
                                        ],
                                        'validation' => [
                                            'validate-select' => true,
                                        ],
                                        'filterBy' => [
                                            'target' => '${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.country_id',
                                            'field' => 'country_id',
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                    'postcode' => [
                                        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/post-code',
                                        'validation' => [
                                            'required-entry' => true,
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                    'company' => [
                                        'validation' => [
                                            'min_text_length' => 0,
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                    'fax' => [
                                        'validation' => [
                                            'min_text_length' => 0,
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                    'telephone' => [
                                        'config' => [
                                            'tooltip' => [
                                                'description' => 'For delivery questions.',
                                            ],
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                ]
                            ),
                        ],
                    ],
                ];
            }
            unset($configuration[$paymentGroup]['methods']);
        }

        return $output;
    }
```

My intention is to overwrite the `processPaymentConfiguration` method and redefine the component to point to the component in my custom module. Something along the lines of...

**How I want to modify the `processPaymentConfiguration` method**

```
/**
     * Inject billing address component into every payment component
     *
     * @param array $configuration list of payment components
     * @param array $elements attributes that must be displayed in address form
     * @return array
     */
    private function processPaymentConfiguration(array &$configuration, array $elements)
    {
        $output = [];
        foreach ($configuration as $paymentGroup => $groupConfig) {
            foreach ($groupConfig['methods'] as $paymentCode => $paymentComponent) {
                if (empty($paymentComponent['isBillingAddressRequired'])) {
                    continue;
                }
                $output[$paymentCode . '-form'] = [
                    'component' => 'MilkJarCookies_OrderDeliveryDate/js/view/billing-address',
                    'displayArea' => 'billing-address-form-' . $paymentCode,
                    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'deps' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'dataScopePrefix' => 'billingAddress' . $paymentCode,
                    'sortOrder' => 1,
                    'children' => [
                        'form-fields' => [
                            'component' => 'uiComponent',
                            'displayArea' => 'additional-fieldsets',
                            'children' => $this->merger->merge(
                                $elements,
                                'checkoutProvider',
                                'billingAddress' . $paymentCode,
                                [
                                    'country_id' => [
                                        'sortOrder' => 115,
                                    ],
                                    'region' => [
                                        'visible' => false,
                                    ],
                                    'region_id' => [
                                        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/region',
                                        'config' => [
                                            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                                            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/select',
                                            'customEntry' => 'billingAddress' . $paymentCode . '.region',
                                        ],
                                        'validation' => [
                                            'validate-select' => true,
                                        ],
                                        'filterBy' => [
                                            'target' => '${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.country_id',
                                            'field' => 'country_id',
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                    'postcode' => [
                                        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/post-code',
                                        'validation' => [
                                            'required-entry' => true,
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                    'company' => [
                                        'validation' => [
                                            'min_text_length' => 0,
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                    'fax' => [
                                        'validation' => [
                                            'min_text_length' => 0,
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                    'telephone' => [
                                        'config' => [
                                            'tooltip' => [
                                                'description' => 'For delivery questions.',
                                            ],
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                ]
                            ),
                        ],
                    ],
                ];
            }
            unset($configuration[$paymentGroup]['methods']);
        }

        return $output;
    }
```

Here is the catch... I have already created a `LayoutProcessorPlugin` since I needed to introduce new fields into the checkout shipping page.

**Contents of my di.xml file**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="order-delivery-date"
                type="MilkJarCookies\OrderDeliveryDate\Block\Plugin\Checkout\LayoutProcessorPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

The `LayoutProcessorPlugin.php` below adds a date, time slot and special instructions fields.

**MilkJarCookies/OrderDeliveryDate/Block/Plugin/Checkout/LayoutProcessorPlugin.php**

```
namespace MilkJarCookies\OrderDeliveryDate\Block\Plugin\Checkout;

use Bss\OrderDeliveryDate\Block\Plugin\Checkout\LayoutProcessorPlugin as BaseLayoutProcessorPlugin;

class LayoutProcessorPlugin extends BaseLayoutProcessorPlugin
{
    protected $_helper;
    const DELIVERY_FORM_DISPLAY_AT_SHIPPING_ADDRESS = 0;
    const DELIVERY_FORM_DISPLAY_AT_SHIPPING_METHOD = 1;
    const DELIVERY_FORM_DISPLAY_AT_REVIEW_PAYMENTS = 2;

    public function __construct(
        \MilkJarCookies\OrderDeliveryDate\Helper\Data $helper
    ) {
        $this->_helper = $helper;
    }

    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {
        $container = null;
        if(!$this->_helper->isEnabled()) return $jsLayout;
        if($this->_helper->getDisplayAt() == self::DELIVERY_FORM_DISPLAY_AT_SHIPPING_ADDRESS) {
            $container = 'shipping-address-fieldset';
        } elseif($this->_helper->getDisplayAt() == self::DELIVERY_FORM_DISPLAY_AT_SHIPPING_METHOD) {
            $container = 'before-shipping-method-form';
        }
        // before place order
        if($this->_helper->getDisplayAt() == self::DELIVERY_FORM_DISPLAY_AT_REVIEW_PAYMENTS){
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children']['before-place-order']['children']['shipping_arrival_date'] = [
                'component' => 'MilkJarCookies_OrderDeliveryDate/js/form/element/abstract',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'MilkJarCookies_OrderDeliveryDate/form/element/date',
                    'options' => [],
                    // 'disabled' => true,
                    'id' => 'shipping-arrival-date',
                    'class' => 'test'
                ],
                'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.shipping_arrival_date',
                'label' => 'Delivery Date',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'visible' => true,
                'validation' => [],
                'sortOrder' => 200,
                'id' => 'shipping-arrival-date'
            ];
        }else{
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
            ['shippingAddress']['children'][$container]['children']['shipping_arrival_date'] = [
                'component' => 'MilkJarCookies_OrderDeliveryDate/js/form/element/abstract',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'MilkJarCookies_OrderDeliveryDate/form/element/date',
                    'options' => [],
                    // 'disabled' => true,
                    'id' => 'shipping-arrival-date'
                ],
                'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.shipping_arrival_date',
                'label' => 'Delivery Date',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'visible' => true,
                'validation' => [],
                'sortOrder' => 200,
                'id' => 'shipping-arrival-date'
            ];
        }

        if($this->_helper->getTimeSlot()){
            // before place order
            if($this->_helper->getDisplayAt() == self::DELIVERY_FORM_DISPLAY_AT_REVIEW_PAYMENTS){
                $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children']['before-place-order']['children']['delivery_time_slot'] = [
                    'component' => 'MilkJarCookies_OrderDeliveryDate/js/form/element/select',
                    'config' => [
                        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'MilkJarCookies_OrderDeliveryDate/form/element/select',
                        'id' => 'delivery-time-slot'
                    ],
                    'caption' => 'Please select delivery time slot',
                    'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.delivery_time_slot',
                    'label' => 'Delivery Time Slot',
                    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'visible' => true,
                    'validation' => [],
                    'options' => $this->_helper->getTimeSlot(),
                    'sortOrder' => 201,
                    'id' => 'delivery-time-slot',
                ];
            }else{
                $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
                ['shippingAddress']['children'][$container]['children']['delivery_time_slot'] = [
                    'component' => 'MilkJarCookies_OrderDeliveryDate/js/form/element/select',
                    'config' => [
                        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'MilkJarCookies_OrderDeliveryDate/form/element/select',
                        'id' => 'delivery-time-slot'
                    ],
                    'caption' => 'Please select delivery time slot',
                    'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.delivery_time_slot',
                    'label' => 'Delivery Time Slot',
                    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'visible' => true,
                    'validation' => [],
                    'options' => $this->_helper->getTimeSlot(),
                    'sortOrder' => 201,
                    'id' => 'delivery-time-slot',
                ];
            }
        }
        // before place order
        if($this->_helper->getDisplayAt() == self::DELIVERY_FORM_DISPLAY_AT_REVIEW_PAYMENTS){
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children']['before-place-order']['children']['shipping_arrival_comments'] = [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/textarea',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/textarea',
                    'id' => 'shipping-arrival-comments',
                    'rows' => 5
                ],
                'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.shipping_arrival_comments',
                'label' => 'Special Instructions',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'visible' => true,
                'validation' => [],
                'sortOrder' => 202,
                'id' => 'shipping-arrival-comments'
            ];
        }else{
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
            ['shippingAddress']['children'][$container]['children']['shipping_arrival_comments'] = [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/textarea',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/textarea',
                    'id' => 'shipping-arrival-comments',
                    'rows' => 5
                ],
                'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.shipping_arrival_comments',
                'label' => 'Special Instructions',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'visible' => true,
                'validation' => [],
                'sortOrder' => 202,
                'id' => 'shipping-arrival-comments'
            ];
        }
        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

In short: I am not quite sure how I can utilize the `LayoutProcessorPlugin` to overwrite the `processPaymentConfiguration` method or how to correctly overwrite that method so that I can overwrite the `billing-address.js` component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could overwrite the JS file in `Your\Module\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js`:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address": "MilkJarCookies_OrderDeliveryDate/js/view/billing-address"
        }
    }
};
```

Another way would be to manually replace the text in the config array at the end of your `afterProcess` plugin:

```
    $json = json_encode($jsLayout);
    $json = str_replace(
        'Magento_Checkout\/js\/view\/billing-address',
        'MilkJarCookies_OrderDeliveryDate\/js\/view\/billing-address',
        $json
    );
    $jsLayout = json_decode($json);
```

This could be made a lot more efficient, it's just an example.

Comment: The require.js way is the way I used to overwrite the billing-address.js file